# Spectral Clustering and Multi-Dimensional Scaling in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I used Spectral Clustering to cluster some word feature vectors. I used cosine similarity matrix of the word vectors as the precomputed affinity matrix in Spectral Clustering algo. This is what I got as three cluster. I used the cluster assignment as the labels to color the points.

[image]
However I used the same cosine similarity matrix and calculated the distance matrix from it.

```
dist=1-cosimilarity.
```

And used Multi-Dimensional Scaling algo to visualize the points in a 3 Dimensional Space. This is what I got from that. I used that actual points label to color the points.

[image]

If you see MDS groupings those don't show any distinct cluster grouping while Spectral one does seem to show three pretty decent clusters.

1). What do you think the reason might be?. Because MDS is simply plotting the points on a lower dimensional scale by the virtue of the distance between them (MDS reduces the distance between the points in the same proportion as the distance between them in higher dimensions, thereby preserving the proportion of between points distance same) and not clustering them using some distance criteria?. I was hoping to see the spectral result a bit similar to the MDS one since both are using the distance measure. Just that clustering is fusing the nearby points into one. While MDS is plotting as it is. But in MDS I have used the actual labels of the points. So that indicates the ground truth?.

2). Any suggestions to improve on the clustering using some other algo or this looks decent?.

EDIT:

It appears there are three groups , but red is overlapping with blue and green groups. But what if I say it appears to us it is overlapping because of our inability to see things beyond 3D (which anyway is 2D on a computer screen). What if the red points are way above blue and green if we happen to see them in 3D or even more dimensions.

Take an example below:

Lets say you are looking at three points.

[image]

Imagine the points you see above appear to you if you look for 1D. Maybe right from the top.

Now what if you get to see these points in 2D. It appears as below.

[image]

If you see now, all the three points appear separated. Just that we were able to see the points in 2D we were actually able to see the relationship between the points which appeared to us as in straight line when visualized from top and in 1D.

So do you think the clustering result like above might actually be a clearly separated set of points and at a pretty far distance from each group in reality if we are able to visualize them in 3D which to us currently appears not well separated?. Would that mean there might be cases like above where visualization of clustering result might not be the right way as it might lead to conclusions as above?.

EDIT II:

Ran A DBSCAN algo using the following code: Used the earlier calculated distance matrix as pre-computed matrix for DBSCAN

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
    dbscan=DBSCAN(metric='precomputed')
    cluster_labels=dbscan.fit_predict(dist)
```

Please remember in all spectral and DBSCAN the points which I am plotting is the result out of Multi-Dimensional Scaling algo to three dimensions.

DBSCAN graph: 
[image]

EDIT III:

Calculation of Similarity and Distance Matrix:

```
 from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

    cossim= cosine_similarity(X)

    dist=1-cossim

    dist=np.round(dist, 2)
```

EDIT IV:

Since Anony-Mousse suggested maybe Cosine Similarity might not be the right metric , so now what I did I just used the original bag of words design matrix in DBSCAN algo and did not provide any distance matrix as pre-computed option to it. And left it to sklearn to calculate the right affinity matrix. Now this is what I get. Just one cluster. That's it. It doesn't separate the points at all. 
Please remember this is the same bag of words matrix of data points as the distance matrix used above. The underlying data points are same.

[image]

EDIT V:

Converting count data in bag of words to tf-idf data.

**1). Ran DBSCAN on pre-computed Distance matrix of tf-idf bag of words data.**
 In all the earlier approaches I have simply used count bag of words matrix as the base. Now I am using tf-idf matrix as the base for distance of cosine similarity.

**DBSCAN on Distance matrix:** 
[image]

It kind of gives two types of points but again no separation.

**DBSCAN on original Tf-idf bag of words matrix:**

[image]

Just one single red blob.

**Spectral on cosine similarity matrix of tf-idf data:**

[image]

Just look at it. It is even worse than the result I get when I used spectral on similarity matrix of count bag of words data. Using tf-idf is simply screwing things up for spectral.

**Spectral on Similarity matrix of count data:**

[image]

If you see Spectral when done on just count data is giving still some local groupings while done on tf-idf data it is all mixed up.

Secondly I have 4000 features. To visualize I need to do max in 3 dimensions. So for that I am using results out of MDS. MDS is like PCA so if someone need to visualize the points either MDS or PCA needs to be done.

***EDIT VI:***

So as per Anony-Mousse comments that MDS is screwing things, I thought why not try with PCA. So I get my clusters from DBSCAN or Spectral and then I plot the first three PC's from a PCA . Here is the code I wrote for PCA. The docs_bow here can be tf-idf or even normal count docs_bow.

```
def PCA(docs_bow): 
    """ This function carries out PCA of the dataset
    """

    #Doing PCA (SVD)
    U,S,Vt=np.linalg.svd(docs_bow,full_matrices=False)
    # Projection matrix with Principal Component Loading vectors. Transpose of Vt.(Right singular vectors)
    W=Vt.T
    # Keep only the top 3 Dimensions
    W=W[:,0:3]

    # Finding our Projected datapoints on those two PC's
    PC=np.dot(docs_bow,W)

    return PC
```

**Spectral on cosine matrix and plotting result of MDS:** 
[image]

**Spectral on cosine matrix and first three PC's of PCA:** 
[image]

**DBSCAN of Distance Matrix and MDS first three dimensions:** 
[image]

**DBSCAN of distance matrix and first three PC's of PCA:**
[image]

MDS seem to give better visualization than PCA. I am not what else one can use to reduce dimensions for visualizing a high dimension data.

Answer (score 7):

If you **disable the colors**, how many clusters do you see?

I'd say **there is only one big cluster in this data set**, at least with this preprocessing/visualization.

The three clusters you get from spectral clustering are *meaningless*. It's essentially doing quantization, but *it did not discover structure*. It minimized squared deviations by chunking the data into three similarly sized chunks. But if you would run it again, it would probably produce similar looking, but different chunks: **the result is largely random**, sorry.

Do not expect classes to agree with clusters. As you can see in this data set, it may have three labels, but only one big messy "cluster".

Its easy to produce this effect:

```
from sklearn import datasets, cluster
data=datasets.make_blobs(5000, 3, 1)[0]
c=cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=3).fit_predict(data)
colors = np.array([x for x in 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk'])
scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],color=colors[c].tolist())
```

produces this:

[image: Meaningless Spectral Clustering]

Notice how similar this is to your result? Yet, this is a **single gaussian, there are no clusters here**. Spectral clustering produced 3 clusters here as requested, but they are totally meaningless.

Always check your results if they are *meaningful*. It's really easy to get something that looks like a nice partitioning, but that is a random convex partitioning. **Just because it produced clusters doesn't mean the clusters are *there*!** - Algorithms such as k-means and spectral clustering are prone to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia

Can you see the cluster in this face? ;-) Is it real?

[image]

Here is a rather successful projection of a text data set using MDS. It shows a number of clusters stretching out into different directions of the data space. K-means and variants will not work well on this data set. Gaussian Mixture Modeling would work, but only on the projected data.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understood this. The algorithm is labelling the same cluster points together. Just that they are not very well separated. Its not like the algo is giving the label points different from each other like the graph you see for MDS. 

It can also be that because we are visualizing things in 2d we aren't able to see the difference between the clusters. What if in reality there is a space

Comment: MDS shows the real labels. Spectral is a projected k-means, it will produce clusters even when there are none. Generate a single 3d Gaussian, annd run spectral clustering on it. It will look just like what you got.

Comment: MDS shows the real labels. Spectral is a projected k-means, it will produce clusters even when there are none. Generate a single 3d Gaussian, annd run spectral clustering on it. It will look just like what you got.

Comment: See the example I added. This is how meaningless clusters look like - the data is only a *single* gaussian, not three clusters. Spectral clustering produced a totally meaningless result.

Comment: Ok So let me try to undetstand it better and excuse me if I come out more inquisitive. You are highlighting some interesting things. 

So what you are saying is that even with One Gaussian distribution we have three clusters. Then does it mean Spectral Clustering is totally useless algorithm or it gives wrong  result?. What I am trying to understand is why it does local grouping of points (red together, green together etc). With local grouping it appears as if there are pockets of points close to each other. Its not like totally scattered right?

Comment: My one question is why is it grouping nearby points as same cluster labels? Why not one in red area and one in blue area as blue. If it is grouping certain points together and calling them same cluster then don't you think it is finding some structure in those set of observations and trying to tell its similar?

Comment: Spectral clustering uses k-means. Just like k-means it will always give you k clusters, even if they are not there for real. It is a quantization method, it doesn't recognize shapes or patterns or clusters per se (clusters may coincide with a good quantization). That is what I demonstrated with the picture.

Comment: It doesn't mean these methods are useless. But I would only use them on data where I can visualize the results to verify if it worked. Yoir actual problem probably is the distance function, or the data. As is, either your data or your distance function *destroyed* the structure.

Comment: yes thats right spectral first reduces dimensions and then uses k means to get clusters. I used the cosine simiarity matrix between the word vectors(Bag of words model) to do spectral. Are you suggesting that this distance function might have been the problem?. 

My concern is this. If spectral and k means alway give cluster even if nothing is present then how do we suppose to know where to use them and on which data. Its like having apriori info that this data is where we would get n clusters and so lets use k means of cluster. If given a dataset how to figure out which one to use.

Comment: In quantization, you either know k, or you can choose it freely by whatever works best for the next step - it doesn't need to be a meaningful clustering.

Comment: Make sure you don't pass a cosine *similarity* matrix to a function that expects a distance matrix, or the other way round. Also make sure it doesn't expect the *data* matrix - it may silently cast the similarity to a data matrix, unfortunately. So double-check the documentation.

Comment: Ok here is the thing. I passed similarity matrix of word vectors only to spectral algo. 

But just now I also tried DBSCAN algo by passing the distance matrix. And it seem to give totally worse results. Spectral atleast seem to suggest there are few points close to each other to which it is coloring same. DBSCN is all random. I thought DBSCAN might give better results as it take care of noise and also no._of clusters. What could be going wrong with clustering here. Please check the edit for DBSCAN graph.

Comment: Your visualization probably suffers from the same problem - your distance/similarity is screwed up, so the MDS visualization mixes everything randomly.

Comment: The similarity matrix is calculated as shown in EDIT III

So I am not sure why is that screwed. I do see the values right. For same vectors Distance matrix has value 0 and so on. Then what do you think is wrong with this distance matrix?. I used distance matrix for MDS and DBSCAN and Similarity matrix for Spectral.

Comment: 1-cos is not *metric*. Some of the projections may require a metric. I'm even surprised you got anything from DBSCAN without carefully thinking about the parameters. But **if cosine doesn't work for your data, anything using cosine will not work either**. That is my message: did you check that cosine is a *good* measure for your data? Clearly **your visualization doesn't visualize what DBSCAN used**, because the clusters are not connected but mixed.

Comment: Ok. I have a bag of words word vectors representing n documents as word vectors. Cosine similarity is one very good measure of similarity between vectors especially for text data. So I used that. Why do you think that is not right for text data?. My understanding is that for text data cosine similarity works well. 

Secondly then how does one find the right metric for the data if cosine is not right?.

Comment: Experiment. With normalization, weighting, feature selection etc.

Comment: Please check EDIT IV. I used DBSCAN from sklearn but not with any distance matrix as you suggested maybe that might not be the right matrix. So used the original bag of words design matrix. And left it to sklearn to get the right affinity distance matrix. And see what I got. Just one cluster and no ability to cluster it. I am not sure what is happening here. This doesn't even give any clusters while if I use the distance matrix it does give two clusters all mixed up

Comment: Do not expect the default `eps` to work. It doesn't. The expected behavior of DBSCAN is to put everything into noise if `eps` is too small, and everything into one cluster if `eps` is too big. But the main problem is that you treat functions like magic black boxes, and expect them to work... **you have to look inside the box, and understand what it does, or you won't be able to use it right**. Same holds for MDS, and your data and distance.

Comment: Remember that I said MDS didn't work with your parameters either. Your labeled figure 2 doesn't look *any* better. Don't expect an insight from a single *blob* like that ever.

Comment: So what is your suggestion?. I didn't want to keep tweaking with eps so thought lets try using the default values. Looking at all these results do you think this data is not having any signal for clustering or something is amiss?. I am going to try the cosine similarity and distance matrix by converting the bag of words data into tf-idf. All of this until now is a count distribution of bag of words. But am not sure if that is going to help either

Comment: If there was signal, it was destroyed by MDS or cosine. Read up on DBSCAN why there *is* no reasonable default.

Comment: ok. So if the signal was destroyed by MDS and Cosine then what do you think should have been tried?. I can try spectral directly on the bag of words data but am not sure it would again give the right results. Or I can try some other clustering approach without using any pre-computed similarity or distance matrix and can share results. But again I doubt it has to do with cosine or MDS etc.

Comment: Try other visualization than MDS first? Something where you can *see* clusters in your data.

Comment: Please check my EDIT V. MDS needs to be done as I have 4000 features. And any result of clustering needs to be visualized max in 3 dimensions. I can do PCA or MDS, but would need to reduce the dimensionality and then visualize. Thats why MDS is used

Comment: I agree that you need *some* projection. But your MDS doesn't work. Either it does not work for your data, or you are using it wrong. **Currently, this visualization is useless!** You do not see anything in that blob.

Comment: Well since u said MDS is useless I did PCA and plotting the first three PC's of bag of words matrix both for Spectral clusters and DBSCAN clusters. See Edit VI.  MDS seem to give better visualization that PCA. I am not sure what else one can use to reduce dimensions for visualization.

Comment: Wjy do you think the MDS visualization worked better? I don't think it worked at all. The PCA makes much more sense (but the data still doesn't appear to have clusters...)

Comment: Why do you think PCA makes more sense?. It is not giving a good visualization of the data. At least MDS is visualizing the data with points spread out. What is the reason you think PCA visualization makes more sense to you?

Comment: Define "good visualization". PCA shows a tiny bit of structure. MDS shows a big Gaussian-like blob, so there is clearly something wrong there. If you want the data more spread-out, zoom in.

Comment: I am not sure what structure you meant by PCA. It hardly shows anything. With MDS atleast we see some points close together and visualization pretty clean. My main concern is this. In this particular problem I know the ground truth labels so I can check and say this particular clustering is not good even if visualization says so. But in most cases I won't have that. Now what I am seeing from this exercise is that on changing any kind metric, like if you do MDS on distance matrix where dist=1-cossim then I get something like above. If I do eucl distance then its totally lost.

Comment: Same if I use PCA instead of MDS to visualize then I get completely different visualization. How does then someone going to know which is a decent clustering to accept?

Comment: MDS looks like my Gaussian. That isn't structure, but random. That is also what your labels look like: randomly spread out in the data. (But you do realize that data *doesn't* have to have a "decent" clustering?)

Comment: I have added an image of a reasonable MDS projection, where some structure can be seen (but it probably is still too hard to cluster for k-means and AP).

Comment: May I ask what did u do here? So you had a bag of words design matrix and then you calculated a distance matrix out of that and used that in MDS algo? Secondly when you said K means won't work and GMM would, how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Agree with Has QUIT--Anony-Mousse. Frankly speaking, in Cluster Analysis : **clusters should not intersect**, as I remember (+ K-means clustering does not solve the problem of outliers, DBSCAN can solve). And with MDS results you cannot conclude (moreover: use recieved scores further on in analysis), just can visualize for graphical representation as per manifold / sub-manifolds